# I want to relocate my Logic Pro sound library to this WD hard drive that I briefly used as a time machine drive

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, logic

I understand that time machine hard drives can't be used for relocating Logic sound library, which explains why Logic errors saying it can't relocate to the drive. But considering that the drive is no longer time machine, I thought this was odd. I figured that maybe there was some meta  data on the drive that caused the system to think it was still time machine, so I went into the hidden folders and deleted all the weird time machine related files/folders. (.com.apple.timemachine.supported, .fseventsd, .Spotlight-V100, .Trashes, .DocumentRevisions-V100). After doing this I still get the same error. Maybe there's still some sort of time machine related meta data on the drive. Does any one have any ideas ?

Comment: Is there anything of importance on the drive? If not, try erasing it.